# Regular expression to check repeating character or digit, check lowercase,uppercase,capital

Tags: php, regex

please help me..i'm stuck in here..

What i actually want is to check the password from repeating single character or digit.

**Requirement for repeating**

aaaa = false,

abbb = false

abag = false

a33f = false

abcd1234 = true

there is only once for a character should have in password. If more than once repeated, error returns. So hard to explain.

this is my draft code.

1)first i need to check whether the global configuration for repeating character is allowed or not, if yes my password can have repeating char or digit otherwise it would't. After this, i need to check whether the global configuration for lowercase,uppercase or capitals allowed or not.

```
if($globalCOnf['repeat_pass']=="yes")//allowed
{
   //do nothing
}
else //not allowed
{
   //stuck here :(
   if(preg_match('/(.)\1{1,}/',$user_input_pass)) //only check "aaaa" not "aba"
   {
       echo "change password";
   }
   else 
   {
      if($globalCOnf['having_lower_upper_capital']=="yes")//allowed
      {
        //do nothing
      }
      else
      {
          // can't continue
      }

   }

}
```

Comment: I think it should be `preg_match('/(.)\1{2,}` because that letter should be repeated at least once, therefore, use {2,}

Comment: not working.. how about this string "abata". Password not allowed to have more than once single character or digits. See requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_count_values` for this (*An alternate regex free solution*)

```
<?php
$password = 'abcdfa';
if(max(array_count_values(str_split($password)))>1)
{
    echo "Choose another password as words you can't have repeatable characters";
}
```

**`OUTPUT:`**

```
Choose another password as words you can't have repeatable characters
```

You get that output because `a` is repeated two times.

Comment: yess it works.. but how about checking lowercase,uppercase,capital for the last condition??

Comment: @metallurgical, `A` is a different character from `a`.  Did you want to treat them as the same?  If so, use [`strtolower($password)`](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php).

Comment: @ghoti That would work, but could pose a problem if someone thinks their password is Abcde123 and entered into DB as abcde123 and later wants to login using Abcde123; it's a possibility that can't be ruled out. There would need an indicator stating that there was uppercase letter detected.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Right , but that has nothing to do with `ghoti` :) because OP wanted it as such.

Comment: Well, it does in regards to using `strtolower()` @ShankarDamodaran

Comment: if i want password become like this "aBcd123",should i used this code strtolower($password)?? i think, all the password will become lowercase even i need the uppercase.

Comment: @metallurgical, Nope you should not do that _seriously_ ! The above code detects this password `aBcd123b` as perfect since both `b` and `B` are considered different.

Comment: My suggestion was to use `strtolower($password)` for the **test**.  You won't be storing the password in the database, you'll be storing a hash of it.  Do you want, for example, `Abca` to be permitted as a password?  If not, then use: `if(max(array_count_values(str_split(strtolower($password)())>1)`

Comment: Something like this would first detect if there an uppercase letter `if(preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $password))` then continue with the rest of the script if none is detected; short & sweet and built for speed ;-)

Comment: Please be nice to the Internet, and [don't store passwords in your database](http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: @ghoti I think you meant *"and don't store (**plain text**) passwords in your database"* ;-) Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

Comment: You will need to go over the entire comments here, to see what the whole discussion was about. You can make your own decision based on those. @metallurgical

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry man, its working now.. i will post the answer for refences.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for the question.**

```
if($globalCOnf['repeat_pass']=="yes")//allowed
{
  //do nothing
}
else //not allowed
{

  if(max(array_count_values(str_split($user_pass)))>1) 
  {
     echo "change your password now!!!";
  }
  else 
  {
     if($globalCOnf['having_lower_upper_capital']=="yes")//allowed
     {
       //do nothing
     }
     else
     {
         if(preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $user_pass))
         {

            echo "Can't use uppercase";
         }
     }

  }

}
```

100% working.. :)

Comment: Glad you got it working . +1 for Remodifying it to your own form.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this -

```
(\d+).*\1
```

If you get any match there is a repeated character.

Answer (score 0):

Just allow zero or more characters between two duplicate characters.  If there is a match, then the string failed to pass the validation.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca7469750c4e72fd36c3346863de847bcb2f7806))

```
$passwords=['aaaa','abbb','abAg','a33f','abcd1234'];
foreach($passwords as $pass){
    echo "$pass: ";
    if(!preg_match('/([a-zA-Z\d]).*\1/',$pass)){
        echo "valid\n";
    }else{
        echo "failed\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
aaaa: failed
abbb: failed
abAg: valid
a33f: failed
abcd1234: valid
```

Or as one-line: `echo preg_match('/([a-zA-Z\d]).*\1/',$pass)?'failed':'valid'`

Using this type of pattern is much more direct that generating a temporary array of characters and counting their occurrences and checking the highest count.